# How do I separate user accounts in Django ?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to create an app that allows recording of medical information however I am having problems with seperating the user accounts so currently all users see the same information entered. Anyone familiar with django knows how to set the proper permissions and roles and is willing to help a newby out?

I want the user to only access to the account the user creates and the records that the user create.

This is my github [link](https://github.com/iivri/Medical_repository-)

If you are able to to help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check this it may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

Comment: add user = models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User) and when querying your model filter it on request.user

Comment: @Serjik The `user = models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)` is giving an error : 

`user = models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)`
`NameError: name 'django' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list only the user's records in your `/home` . You only need to change the query in your home/views.py, from `Identity_unique.objects.all()` to `Identity_unique.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

class Identity_view(TemplateView):

```
def get(self, request):
    form = Identity_form()
    Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}
    return render(request, self.template_name, var)
```

Or if you want to filter objects in your Django Admin panel you should read this:

- [Django Documentation:  ModelAdmin.get_queryset(request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom user model with an extra field user_type.
  https://github.com/samimsk/debatehub/blob/master/devdebatehub/UserApp/models.py

Implemented here.